# JPA many-to-many: unclear why join table is empty after persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement simple Many-To-Many association using JPA (Hibernate 4) + Spring. Have seen tons of helloworld-like examples where join table is updated automatically when saving entities from 2 associated tables.

However this is not happening in my case - even if I set bidirectional association and cascade, join table is not getting updated on **em.persist()**. While looking to why is this, I came to [this answer here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439748/1990089), which suggests to use **em.persist(); em.flush();** to resolve this problem. I tried - miracle, persisting works fine! But... why???

**Questions:**

1. Why should I use flush() here?
2. Is this mentioned somewhere in official JPA/Hibernate documentation?
3. Should I call flush() after each persist()/update()/remove() when working with many-to-many associations? What are possible downsides of such approach - performance, side effects?

Here is related code.

Entity classes

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="ROLE")
    public class Role extends EntityBase implements Comparable
    {   
       @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
       @JoinTable(name = "ROLE_PERMISSION", 
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="permission_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
       private Set permissions = new HashSet();

       //... other code (getters/setters/extra columns) is omitted ...
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name="PERMISSION")
    public class Permission extends EntityBase
    {   
       @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       private Set roles = new HashSet();

       //... other code (getters/setters/extra columns) is omitted ...
    }
```

Generic DAO implementation (being used by my concrete DAOs):

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager")
    public abstract class GenericDaoImpl implements GenericDao
    {  
       @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
       protected EntityManager em;

       public T create( final T t )
       {
          em.persist(t);
          // em.flush(); - if I put this here, all works well (and fails if I'm not)
          return t;
       }

       // ... other code is omitted ...
    }
```

Service layer method which I'm trying to test:

```
    @Component("securityService")
    public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService
    {
       // ... other code is omitted ...   

       @Transactional(value="transactionManager", 
          rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false)
       public void createRole( Role role )
       {
          Validate.notNull( role, "Role should not be null" );
          roleDao.create( role );
       }
    }
```

And finally my TestNG integration test (uses in-memory H2 DB):

```
    @ContextConfiguration(
       locations={"/META-INF/beans-test.xml"})
    @TransactionConfiguration(
       transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
    public class SecurityServiceImplIT 
       extends AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests
    {
       @Autowired
       @Qualifier("securityService")
       private SecurityService securityService;

       @Test
       @Transactional(value = "transactionManager")
       public void createRole_createRoleWithPermissions()
       {
          // Add test data to DB.
          super.executeSqlScript( TESTDATA_PATH, false);
          // Remove all associations between permissions and roles, need
          // clear intermediate table for this test case.
          super.simpleJdbcTemplate.update( 
             "delete from DB_TEST.ROLE_PERMISSION;" );
          super.simpleJdbcTemplate.update( 
             "delete from DB_TEST.ROLE;" );

          final Role role = new Role();
          role.setName( "Test role" );
          role.addPermission( securityService.getAllPermissions().get(0) );
          final int expectedPermissionCount = 1;

          securityService.createRole(role);

          // This is always passed
          Assert.assertEquals( super.countRowsInTable( "DB_TEST.ROLE" ), 1, 
             "New role should be added, so table should contain 1 row" );

          // This is failed if I'm not using flush() in my DAO.
          Assert.assertEquals( super.countRowsInTable( "DB_TEST.ROLE_PERMISSION" ), 
             expectedPermissionCount, "Role-permission associations should be added" );
       }

       // ... other code is omitted ...
    }
```

Hibernate debug log (without flush() call in DAO):

```
Hibernate: insert into DB_TEST.ROLE (id, version, description, name) values (null, ?, ?, ?)

...

aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl: Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
aa TRACE org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions: No unresolved entity inserts that depended on [[xxx.logic.db.model.Role#4]]
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: xxx.logic.db.model.Role
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: Cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: xxx.logic.db.model.Role.permissions
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.EJB3CascadingAction: Cascading to persist: xxx.logic.db.model.Permission
aa TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener: Persistent instance of: xxx.logic.db.model.Permission
aa TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener: Ignoring persistent instance
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: Done cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: xxx.logic.db.model.Role.permissions
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: xxx.logic.db.model.Role
aa TRACE org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions: No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl: Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
aa TRACE org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions: No unresolved entity inserts that depended on [[xxx.logic.db.model.Role#4]]
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: xxx.logic.db.model.Role
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: Cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: xxx.logic.db.model.Role.permissions
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.spi.EJB3CascadingAction: Cascading to persist: xxx.logic.db.model.Permission
aa TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener: Persistent instance of: xxx.logic.db.model.Permission
aa TRACE org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener: Ignoring persistent instance
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: Done cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for collection: xxx.logic.db.model.Role.permissions
aa TRACE org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade: Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_SKIPLAZY for: xxx.logic.db.model.Role
aa TRACE org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions: No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
```

This log is saying that Hibernate is going through the Permissions collection, but ignoring items from there for some reason. I totally don't understand why calling flush() makes any difference here... Generally, flush() is just an ability to explicitly tell Hibernate when to post SQL query to DB.

Can anyone explain this or at least point me to right documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate delays the SQL statements executions until absolutely necessary. This avoids executing unnecessary statements in case the transaction finally rollbacks, which saves time.

In the end, when the transaction is committed, then Hibernate flushes the pending modifications and commits. But since you have configured your tests to rollback and not commit the transaction, this automatic flush never happens, and you need an explicit call to `flush()` to make it execute the insert.

Comment: I've just tested with no automatic transaction rollback - same behavior. Doubt that this is related, generally flush() could change time when SQL is posted to DB, but it should not control the flow hibernate does when performing persist operation. I'm ok to put flush() to all methods of my generic DAO unless this has some major downsides. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't do that. You'll force Hibernate to make many unnecessary roundtrips to the database. How do you determine that it doesn't flush automatically? Have you enabled SQL logging, removed your assertions and let the test go until the end and succeed? Or do you conclude that from the failure of your assertions?

Comment: I've enabled trace logs for hibernate, run test in debug mode and was going line by line checking what hibernate is doing - and could see that in case of no flush() hibernate just didn't generate any insert statements for join table, only one insert for main table. In case with flush() call it generated all inserts. Note that insert of main entity (role) happened right after the create call, first assert always ok.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Did you remove all the assertions, and let the test execute completely (and thus succeed), with SQL logs enabled?

Comment: Yes, I tried - turned off transaction rollback, removed all assertions and enabled traces for hibernate. Same behavoir, i.e. if no flush(), inserts for join table are not generated at all, I see only 1 insert for ROLE table. Log is same as one I've posted.